# printing in python terminal is not what I get in text file

Tags: python, excel

```py
print(text)
with open("Text file","w") as fin:
     fin.write(text)`
```

The printing is aligned in fixed width. The written file is not arranged in the same width but in a haphazard way. I need fixed width to convert into excel.
Cant share images since it is not right.

Printing `text` (on terminal) I get:

```
Locus     67
pocopine  78
```

On the file I get:

```
Lotus  67
pocupine  78
```

Comment: Youe question is ambiguous and not right

Comment: Sorry, I didnt know how to post code

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you show us the text then we might have some idea  what wrong.  As it is, all we have is a vague description. Copy & paste the code that assigns a value to text. Copy the text from your screen (as text not a picture). Then  [edit] your question to show them. Mark both as code with the `{ }` button.

Comment: I added image. Please see if it helps.

Comment: It doesn't help much. You are not showing us what is in the file *as text*, you are showing us how some program renders it on your screen. Open the file in a text editor and copy the text. Then [edit] your question and add the text, and mark that added text as code with the `{ }` button. Then open your code in a text editor and copy it.  Then [edit] your question again and add the code to your question, and mark it as code with the `{ }` button.

Comment: @Poppat Please show what `text` is. What does `"Text file"` look like?

Comment: You say "On the file I get" - how are you arriving at that conclusion? Have you looked at the actual characters being printed and written to file? Where is `text` coming from? Something you could try is `print(list(text))` before the `print(text)` and share the output of that with people here as well.

Comment: Are you using tabs (`"\t"`) to separate the columns?  That would explain your result, and in that case there is absolutely nothing wrong.  Tab processing varies depending on the tools, but Excel can read them just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using formatting

Example:

```
print("%-50s %4.f" % ("Test, Exam", 4))

print("%-"Number of spaces"s %"Decimal points if needed".f" % ("Test, Exam", 4))
```

if you export it to excel and you want the text in different cells you should specify this in question

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).